# How can I create an AppImage of Wine?

Tags: wine, appimage

So I want to package WINE as an AppImage using `appimage-builder`.

First, I wonder if someone already did this, and yes, [here](https://github.com/Hackerl/Wine_Appimage/releases), but it's outdated. I want to make one myself.

Next, I look on the Github page above for how to do this, but it requires PlayOnLinux to have up-to-date stuff, which it does not have.

After that, I looked at the [appimage-builder documentation](https://appimage-builder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro/overview.html), and I got this.

```
version: 1

AppDir:
  path: ./AppDir

  app_info:
    id: org.gnu.bash
    name: bash
    icon: utilities-terminal
    version: 4.4.20
    exec: bin/bash
    exec_args: $@

  apt:
    arch: amd64
    sources:
      - sourceline: 'deb [arch=amd64] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main'
        key_url: 'http://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x3b4fe6acc0b21f32'

    include:
      - bash
      - coreutils
    exclude:
      - dpkg

  test:
    centos:
      image: appimage-builder/test-env:centos-7
      command: "./AppRun -c \"ls\""
      use_host_x: True


AppImage:
  update-information: None
  sign-key: None
  arch: x86_64
```

So what I'm asking is how to change it from bash to wine64 and how to make `hirsute` instead of `bionic`.

Comment: WineHQ Hmm, That's will be quiet the complicated project. Related: https://github.com/ferion11/Wine_Appimage and https://github.com/AppImage/pkg2appimage/pull/418